# Hide and remove line with PHP if empty

Tags: php

I am attempting to hide a field when empty,

So far I have gotten the following to somewhat do what I need

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<textarea id="output">
<?php if(isset($_POST['errorMessage']) && !empty($_POST['errorMessage'])){ ?>
Error message code              -    <?php echo $_POST['errorMessage']; ?>
<?php } ?>
</textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Although I find this just leaves blank space where the field would have been, how can I hide the field and remove the space if the field is empty?

Comment: please provide your html or where you are placing this.. You need to add the full element with in the if statement in order to hide it.

Comment: What field? I don't see any field in your code.

Comment: Where is empty space, Your code already checking with if condition error element is empty or not.

Comment: <?php if(isset($_POST['errorMessage']) && !empty($_POST['errorMessage'])){ ?>
<textarea id="output">
Error message code              -    <?php echo $_POST['errorMessage']; ?>
</textarea>
<?php } ?>

Comment: I sorry I have made some edits to my post if that helps, Basically the 'error message' variable is entered into a form on another page and submitted and is entered into the textarea. Although currently if the variable is empty it will leave a newline where the variable would have been.

Comment: html doesn't really care about newlines, why are you trying to fix it at all? What is the problem you are facing with the generated html?

Comment: The issue is I have at least 10-15 different variables that will be posted on separate lines (this is one example) and if 5 of those 10-15 are empty then it leaves a large blank space in the <textarea>.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the issue I was experiencing

```
if(isset($_POST['documentName']) && 
!empty($_POST['documentName'])){ 
echo 'Document Name                     -    ' . 
($_POST['documentName']) . '
'; 
}
```